# How to use tf.metrics.accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to use [`tf.metrics.accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy) to track the accuracy of my predictions, but I am unsure of how to use the update_op (`acc_update_op` below) that the function returns:

```
accuracy, acc_update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predictions)
```

I was thinking that adding it to `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` would make sense, but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tf.metrics.accuracy` is one of the many streamed metric TensorFlow operations (another one of which is [`tf.metrics.recall`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/recall)). Upon creation, two variables (`count` and `total`) are created in order to accumulate all incoming results for one final outcome. The first returned value is a tensor for the calculation `count / total`. The second op returned is a stateful function which updates these variables. Streamed metric functions are useful when evaluating the performance of a classifier over multiple batches of data. A quick example of use:

```py
# building phase
with tf.name_scope("streaming"):
    accuracy, acc_update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predictions)

test_fetches = {
    'accuracy': accuracy,
    'acc_op': acc_update_op
}

# when testing the classifier    
with tf.name_scope("streaming"):
    # clear counters for a fresh evaluation
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

for _i in range(n_batches_in_test):
    fd = get_test_batch()
    outputs = sess.run(test_fetches, feed_dict=fd)

print("Accuracy:", outputs['accuracy'])
```

> I was thinking that adding it to `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` would make sense, but I am not sure how to do this.

That would not be a good idea unless you are only using the UPDATE_OPS collection for testing purposes. Usually, the collection will already have certain control operations for the training phase (such as moving batch normalization parameters) that are not meant to be run alongside the validation phase. It may be best to either keep them in a new collection or add these operations to the fetch dictionary manually.

Comment: Okay, I see that using `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` doesn't make sense, but what about using `tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES`? How would I go about that?

Comment: `tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES`, you say? That one is meant to be used for keeping summary tensors, so you shouldn't be using that either.There isn't a standard collection key for this, but you can choose one of your own (e.g. 'metric_ops'). Having these operations in a collection only means that you would then be also in charge of making sure that they are executed on each iteration of the evaluation phase.

Comment: I found another solution, would you care to comment? `with tf.control_dependencies([accuracy_op]): tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)`

Comment: That would work, except that a summary would be built each step (usually you would only need one at the final step or shortly afterwards). It might not be the best dependency to model here.